# jQuery withCredentials not working in Safari?

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use jQuery.ajax() withCredentials:true cross-domain however it's not working in Safari for some reason.

It works in Firefox, Chrome and IE (using P3P header) but in Safari it won't authenticate.

My code is pretty simple:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.someurl.com",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Is there something specific I need to do server side for Safari to accept the cookies?

EDIT: It works once I changed "Block cookies and other website data" to never, but obviously this isn't a solution for a public facing website.

Safari does not honor the cookies sent by the server. Here are my headers (only relevant headers shown), pay attention to the two different domains:

```
Request headers:
Referer: https://example.net
Origin: https://example.net
Host: example.org
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Response headers:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: authentication=8xIhPr9m0Fwky0qcE; expires=Fri, 09-Mar-2018 16:59:55 GMT; Max-Age=8640000; path=/; domain=example.org; secure; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.net
```

Is there a CORS header that is missing and that is required by Safari only ?

Answer (score 7):

I'm sorry to say, but there isn't a very elegant solution for this problem.
Apple had recently adopted a strict policy to prevent 3rd party cookies - [link](https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention/)

> This means users only have long-term persistent cookies and website data from the sites they actually interact with and tracking data is removed proactively as they browse the web.

[image]

The best solution I can think of is to redirect the user to a login page hosted in the 3rd party domain and then back to the original page after the login. This way the cookie will be stored (since the user interacted with its domain directly), and you would also be able to interact with it as 3rd party cookie from the original domain.

Comment: Thank you. Redirection was a good approach. I was able to solve the problem using redirection. There is just one point that is bothering me: Using the location header, I can only use GET requests, what means, that the URLs can become pretty long. Also the data is directly visible in the address bar (with POST, the data is hidden at least superficially).

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Yes, location header will be sent with GET requests. can you add some more information about why you have to use the location header? Can you use a simple POST request (with multipart/form-data)

Comment: I replaced my cross-site ajax calls with 302-redirects. That way all browsers honor the cookies set during the requests. As I understand, the only way to POST and redirect is through 307-redirects, and then the same data is posted to the original and the redirected URL. I'm not showing a login form on the 3rd party domain as you were suggesting.